# Double data result mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i wanna show data just like on the table

```
<?php
while(my looping data){
$selectorang2 = mysql_query("SELECT likes.*, user.* FROM likes, user WHERE 
                 likes.uid_fk = u ser.uid AND 
                 likes.idstatus_fk = $data[idstatus]");
while ($peoplelike = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectorang2)) {
    $datajempoler2[] = $peoplelike['nama'];
}
    echo count($datajempoler2);
}
?>
```

the result is

2 4 6 8 10 12 ect.

and data on the table is 2 2 2 2 2 2 etc.
can anyone help me i'm so tired search in google.

Thanks Before.

Comment: In each iteration you are echoing how long the array is. That's why you get increments of 2, because the first one it has 2 elements, the next one 4, etc. Besides of that, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i wanna show id who like's my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialize the datajempoler2 array or it is retaining the older value and adding new elements to it.

```
<?php
while(my looping data) {
    datajempoler2 = array(); // this line need to be added

    $selectorang2 = mysql_query("SELECT likes.*, user.* FROM likes, user WHERE 
                 likes.uid_fk = u ser.uid AND 
                 likes.idstatus_fk = $data[idstatus]");

    while ($peoplelike = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectorang2)) {
        $datajempoler2[] = $peoplelike['nama'];
    }

    echo count($datajempoler2);
}
?>
```

Comment: i think you just change the mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc
but you add datajempoler2 = array(); to
and this is work for me thanks :)

Comment: I have reinitialized the array you count and echo after the first while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because here:

```
  while ($peoplelike = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectorang2)) {
        $datajempoler2[] = $peoplelike['nama'];
    }
```

You set there into array $datajempoler2 twice, and after you make echo, you get:2, 4, 6 and so on

Comment: You wan to get just 2 elements?

Comment: use break operetion  in your loop

Comment: while ($peoplelike = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectorang2)) {
    $datajempoler2[] = $peoplelike['nama']; if(count($datajempoler2) == 2){break;}
}

Comment: @Faytraneozter Have you looked on my solution?